build.gradle error in flutter, Visual Studio Code
It's my first time building an app, and I am doing it on Flutter. However, my build.gradle has an error and when i hover my mouse over it, this is what I get.
Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.3-all.zip'.
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
Build file '/Users/shermanchew/Documents/GitHub/WheresTheHalal/wheres_the_halal/android/app/build.gradle' line: 2
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
Your current JDK is located in /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
You can try some of the following options:

changing the IDE settings.
changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
changing org.gradle.java.home in gradle.properties.

I tried to play around with the recommendations and installed java 11. My JAVA_HOME is pointing to the correct JDK and have added the line "org.gradle.java.home=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11)" to my gradle.properties. I'm not sure how else I can resolve this problem.

Run java -version  in your terminal to check your Java Development Kit version. if the version is still 1.8, which is what your project is complaining about, chances are you did not define the path correctly to your JDK in your shell file.
Try adding these two lines to your shell file:
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/your/jdk11

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

remember to replace /path/to/your/jdk11 with the correct path to your JDK.
save and close your shell and run the
source ~/.bash_profile command in your terminal to apply the changes.
then simply run these commands in your project's root flutter clean and flutter pub get.
this will solve your issue I believe.

Thanks for the suggestion!! However, it shows that my current java version is 11.
openjdk version "11.0.23" 2024-04-16 OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 11.0.23+0) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 11.0.23+0, mixed mode)
